# Can I see checked rules list in a project?

Tags: filter, sonarqube, rules

I made to run sonarqube. And many bugs were caught in the project.
So when I loaded Issues page, I filtered rules like link image...
I think a lot of bugs was caught many rules in the sonarqube. But I can not see all of rules in the left side of a issues page.
Can I see all rules that bugs were caught ??

Sorry about my poor English... And Thanks a lot in advance..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJfbH.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get this list through the UI. However, you could use [web services](https://sonarqube.com/web_api) to

1. get the list of all rules active in the appropriate profile
2. get the issue count in your project for each rule

Comment: If this helped you @js.c, you might [accept] it. :-)